# Alternative to ShowDialog that doesn't block interaction with parents

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

I'm moving an Outlook VBA macro over to VSTO, one part of which involves showing a UserForm mid-execution, with various inputs that the user likely needs to copy/paste from Outlook.

In the VBA this is acheived with:

```
[...]
UserForm.Show vbModeless

Do Until UserForm.Visible = False
    DoEvents
Loop
[...]
```

In VB I have:

```
Dim DealIDForm As New DealIdent 'form class

[...] set up form [...]
DealIDForm.ShowDialog()
[...] process input
```

But this disables interaction with Outlook, so isn't ideal

I've tried:

```
Dim thread As New Thread(Sub()
                            DealIDForm.Show()
                         End Sub)

While DealIDForm.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None 'not yet set
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5))
End While
```

But that just didn't show the form. Is there an alternative I could be using?

Comment: Stopping at a specific line of code while the rest of the application continues to operate is not natural for a GUI application (with the exception of using `ShowDialog()`). The WinForms GUI system is event-based so you're supposed to subscribe to events in order to react to changes. In your case either the [`FormClosing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing) or [`FormClosed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed) event would be appropriate.

Comment: @Mary that's not going to work. Execution will continue before the user has used the form.

Comment: @VisualVincent I think I knew that really, but enjoyed being a lazy programmer in VBA and was hoping to continue that into vb.net. I think I needed your comment as a reminder to play nice and do this properly! The form is reused a lot, so in the new() constructor I'll add some code to set where execution goes after the user finishes. This will make everything a lot easier to follow in the long term, despite being a lot of work tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! IMO it's best to do it right from the beginning :). Comment again if you have further questions. Good luck and good night!